# About Android, how to prevent other apps reading my contacts

Tags: android

I try to write an Android app to prevent other apps reading my contacts, even these apps get the android.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission

I google a lot, but get nothing. Could anyone give me some idea about this app...

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem like possible for me

Comment: if no other application needs/has to/can access your contacts, don't save them in the Contacts database. Use a database that is directly into your application.

Comment: if an app has the READ_CONTACTS permission, it's because it needs it... I don't think you can prevent this behaviour ( and I don't think that's a good idea either ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block the apps which has android.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission.You can get the list of apps which has android.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission through package manager api.

If you dont want to disable those app,you can revoke those permission using-http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java API through reflection.

Following is the method in ApoOpsManager.java which can be used for blocking a permission

> /** @hide */    public void setMode(int code, int uid, String
>   packageName, int mode) {
>
> ```
> try {
>        mService.setMode(code, uid, packageName, mode);
>
>  } 
>  catch (RemoteException e)
>    {
>
>  }
> ```
>
> }

To learn how to use reflection for calling internal/hidden api use:
http://jhshi.me/2014/04/02/get-package-usage-statistics-in-android/.similar

This approach may not work always but ya this is the only workaround which I can think of since there are no direct apis to do it.